# Unable to activate trial licence

Tags: config

I would like to test out Craft Pro to see if it would be a good fit for my next project.

I have one issue. I have followed the instructions to install Craft CMS @ http://site1.craft.dev - but am unable to see the upgrade/test link in the footer?

Here is a screen shot of the domain I have it installed at:-

[image: Domain]

Here is a screen shot of the footer:-

[image: Footer]

How would I activate the trial licence (I am probably missing something obvious, so forgive me if this is the case) :)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it sounds silly, but try refreshing or clicking another tab (like entries). What you should see is in the attached screenshot. [image]

Click that box and click "Try" and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks Peter, gave that a go, but unfortunately it did not help :(

Comment: Try the settings page, @Karnage!

Comment: If carlcs's suggestion doesn't work, could it be that your blocking the outbound request? What happens when you click "Check for Updates?"

Comment: Ok, can't see it on the options page - But, I think you may be onto something with the outbound requests being blocked as when I click on "Check for Updates" I get an error. I am using WAMP - not sure what could be blocking it though?

Comment: What's the exact error message you are getting? Is it possible you are trying to do this from a non admin account?

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I got it working by moving to Bitnami WAMP stack (instead of WAMP Server).

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: FFR, you could check the craft/storage/runtime/logs files and see what the underlying error is. Most likely something to do with cURL from the sound of it.

Answer (score 1):

I found this in the release notes of Craft 2.0.2535:

> The upgrade promo is now only shown on the Settings page if you’re running Craft Client.

Maybe this is also true if you are running Craft Personal? I'd look for the link at the bottom of the settings page...