# How can I purchase Craft Client or Craft Pro?

Tags: upgrades

Docs say 'Right within Craft. If you’re running Craft Personal or Craft Client, there’s a link at the bottom of every page in the CP, which brings up a modal window that handles the whole process.'

I just installed Craft Personal 2.3.2629 and there's no link I can see.

Comment: Sounds like [this was a bug which Brad sorted out](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/7073/45). Closing as a bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug. Brad fixed it. Working now.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Settings page (/admin/settings - reached by clicking on the gear icon at the top right of the control panel) and you should see the following link at the bottom of the page:

[image: Upgrade Craft to take your site to the next level. Show me]

Click on the Show me link and the modal window pops up.

Comment: Not showing for me.

Comment: @user1070143 did you see this question: ["Unable to activate trial licence"](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1816/125)?

Comment: Have you tried visiting another page in the control panel (like Entries), then going back to the Settings page? Or refreshing the Settings page?

Comment: As Brad says in the [question linked to above](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1816/125), check in the craft/storage/runtime/logs files to see what the underlying error is.